# FragmentActivity em tab swiper

Tags: java, android

Eu não estou conseguindo inserir um *FragmentActivity* para tab swiper:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {case 0:
            return new HomeActivity();
        case 1:
            return new ListaBancada();

        }
        return null;

    }
```

a classe é HomeActivity herda de *Fragment*, a ListaBancada *FragmentActivity* e a ListaBancada dá erro no código acima, porque?
Como chamar uma *Activity* aí?

Comment: Não dá pra chamar. O método `getItem()` retorna um `Fragment`, o que é diferente de `FragmentActivity`, que apesar de ser uma activity que suporta conter fragments, ainda assim é uma activity e não um fragment. Fragments são uma coisa, activities são outra.

Comment: E eu posso chamar essa activity dentro do fragment. o fato todo é que eu tenho uma Activity pronta e quero colocar no lugar desse fragment

Comment: Uma activity pode conter fragments, não o contrário. Você terá que converter sua activity em um fragment e usá-lo no switch.

Comment: Ok Piovezan! vou ter que me aprofundar mais nisso muito obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Sem problemas. Postei uma resposta à sua pergunta para você aceitar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não dá pra chamar. O método `getItem()` retorna um `Fragment`, o que é diferente de `FragmentActivity`, que apesar de ser uma *activity* própria para conter *fragments*, ainda assim é uma `Activity` e não um `Fragment`. *Fragments* são uma coisa, *activities* são outra.

Uma *activity* pode conter *fragments*, não o contrário. Você terá que converter sua *activity* em um *fragment* e usá-lo no `switch`.